# Streaming Service Submission Parameter Ambiguous

Tags: streaming, ibm-cloud

I have a Streams application I would like to run in Bluemix streaming service. The application has submission time parameters in two different namespaces but the parameter name is equal. When trying to submit the application the streaming service responds with "submission parameter is ambiguous" (see screen shoot).

[Error: Subission Parameter Ambiguous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15aj.png)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Streams console bug is fixed in a future release. In the meantime, work around the issue by renaming one of the parameters in your SPL code.

You likely have this line in one namespace:

`getSubmissionTimeValue("Period");`

and in another namespace:

`getSubmissionTimeValue("Period");`

Change one of these lines to `getSubmissionTimeValue("Period2");`, or similar.